# Minecraft: Is setting the spawn-monsters setting to false equivalent to peaceful?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In server.properties there is a spawn-monsters setting that you can set to false. It stops them from spawning, but does it remove existing monsters like setting the difficulty to peaceful? In other words, can I allow monsters for a little while and then safely turn them back off, or will creepers that spawned while it was on linger, awaiting unsuspecting victims?

Comment: I never knew peaceful removed monsters... I thought it was just really easy!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of 1.8, setting `difficulty=0` is the new equivalent to peaceful.  `spawn-monsters=false` will still get rid of the nightly mobs, but unless `difficulty=0`, spawners will still spawn, and your health and food will not regenerate.

---

**BEGIN OLD ANSWER:**

In order for the changed setting to take effect, the server must be restarted. until restarted, monsters will still spawn.  After a restart, there should be no monsters.

Comment: Yeah, probably because it only reads the properties file on start, and then the settings are cached.

Comment: @Tchalvak Yes, the server console only says "reading properties file" on the start of the server.

Comment: Right, I assumed I'd have to restart. But when I do it will kill off existing monsters, too (not just prevent new ones from spawning)?

Comment: @Matt I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't, considering that "spawn monsters" is false.

Comment: @Matt, restarting the server removes all the monsters whether `spawn monsters` is true or not

Comment: Which is kinda too bad, since that means you can't keep them as pets.

Comment: As an extra note it also adds health regeneration.